# Who is the announcer in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I wonder, Who is the announcer of league of legends?

I don't mean it's place in the storyline/lore (I don't think there's a lot to know there, it's not like the [Team Fortress 2 announcer](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Announcer))

What I mean is who is the voice actor. Is it someone professional or someone from riot that does a lot more than just the voice actor? I'm curious.

Comment: [Brian Sommer](http://www.briansommer.com/credits_games.html)'s site claims that he voices "Game Announcer, Warwick, the Yeti, and Tryndamere". I suspect that either the site is mistaken, or he voiced an older announcer

Comment: Haha this question would actually be more relevant to Arqade if it was asking about the lore instead

Comment: Valid point @BBz

Comment: @Arkive Some people just have godly vocal ranges

Comment: @BBz I didn't look very hard, but I didn't find any vocal work that was similar to the current announcer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian Sommer was indeed the old announcer voice, but I can't find who the new announcer is.  However there is a relatively exhaustive list on the  [League of Legends Forums](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1948291)  that includes many of the voice actors for the champions, as well as including interviews with voice actors.